# Robot framework, how to compare sound, video file

Tags: comparison, video-capture, video-processing, audio, robotframework

I have sound, video source file and I have to verify my program which open and play this file is work correctly.

I don't know how to verify file like this!

I think i should capture (sound/video) and then compare it to source file.

Till this time, I've searched on the internet but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a real challange for you, I personally have never done this but hopefully I can provide you with some help to set you on your way...

First you need to know that robotframework is run on python so anything you will need to be in python or have python bindings so asking there may be a good start.
In terms of capturing sound I believe it would be eaiser to use a program with a api you can use, I found a document here of someone doing this, as to whether this is still correct I am not sure:

http://www.nektra.com/files/DirectSound_Capture_With_Deviare.pdf

For video capture try looking here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j344j34JBRs

Next would be stripping the video, seperating the audio and video frames and comparing them seperatly. For this you are going to need a video editor, audio comparison library and a tool for comparing images.

In terms of how this would work I dont know as I have never done this...

Why do you need to do this tho, is there not a better way of doing this? Does you application make the video? In which case could just doing some checks on frames, length, file size suffice? You need to provide for information.

This is a bit long for a comment but this answer is incomplete.

Let me know how you get on?

Comment: Yes thank Zenon, I'm following your instruction to make something happen (maybe). Everything just starts, it takes long time (i think so) to research about this.